# Sybase IQ connection in Python

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sybase, sap-iq

I've spent a few days trying to determine how to connect to a Sybase IQ database through Python 3.6. I've tried `pyodbc` and `pymssql`, to no avail. Below are two code snippets that I've been working on, which don't seem to work, no matter what I try.

`pyodbc`:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}',
                          server=server,
                          database=database,
                          port=port,
                          uid=user,
                          pwd=pwd)
```

`pymssql`:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server=server,
                        port=port,
                        user=user,
                        password=pwd,
                        database=database)
```

I've also read that `FreeTds` could be the solution for connecting to a Sybase IQ database; I thought it was installed as part of the `pymssql` database, but I can't seem to figure out how to leverage it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I am aware that `sqlanydb` exists; however, this package makes me downgrade to Python 2.7. My stack is 3.6 and I'd like to not have to move off of that.

Comment: MSSQL client drivers or ODBC drivers will not work for Sybase databases the TDS packet structure is completely different. See this link for more info http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1600/doc/html/san1357754966211.html

Comment: I've seen this `sqlanydb` package come up a few times ... Does it actually work? I've tried installing it on Anaconda and it broke my environment. I should also note that the link within Python support for Windows is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I was able to resolve this issue (On Windows). First, install SQL Anywhere 17 driver. Once that's been installed, in the Windows ODBC Data Sources window, set up a connection using the SQL Anywhere 17, and your Sybase IQ credentials. Once that has been configured and successfully tested, you can use the below code snippet to connect:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

sybase_connection_string = "sqlalchemy_sqlany://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{db}".\
        format(user=user, pwd=pwd, host=host, port=port, db=database)
engine = create_engine(sybase_connection_string)
return engine.connect()
```

I believe you will need the `sqlalchemy_sqlany` module installed via pip, as well as `sqlalchemy`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative use jconn4 or jconn3 driver.
Example of connection:

```py
import jaydebeapi

jar_path = "/drive/jconn4.jar"
driver_name = "com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver"

_ipad = '1.1.1.1'
_port='2638'

con_prop= { "user": 'user', "password": 'pwd'}

connection_url = f"jdbc:sybase:Tds:{_ipad}:{_port}"

conn= jaydebeapi.connect(driver_name, connection_url,con_prop, jar_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jconn4.jar` to connect to Sybase IQ.
I was able to connect with `SAP IQ/16.1.080.1841`

To get jconn4.jar, use `dbeaver` and connect with sybase batabase. Dbeaver will download this jar, which you can use. You can download community edition from official site https://dbeaver.io/

This will require JAVA, to get this running. I used `JDK 1.8.0_181`

Install jaydebeapi for your python with `pip install jaydebeapi`.
I used `python 3.11.0` and `jaydebeapi==1.2.3`

Once you have this, connect like below:

```
import jaydebeapi

jconn4_file_path = '<path/to/jconn4.jar>'
driver = 'com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver'
db_server = '<server hostname>'
db_port = <port>
db_user = '<database username>'
db_password = '<database password>'
db_name = '<database name>'

connection_string = f'jdbc:sybase:Tds:{db_server}:{db_port}?ServiceName={db_name}'

connection = jaydebeapi.connect(
                  driver,
                  connection_string,
                  [db_user, db_pass],
                  jconn4_file_path
             )
```